# detecting negative integer in a string

Tags: c++, string, boolean

Say I take in a string of input and I wanted to check if the user entered a negative number.

```
bool isNegative(string input[]) {
    int i = 0;
    if (input[i] == "-") {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I tried a boolean function to check if the first character is a - sign, representing negative numbers e.g -5, -25.

However, my Netbeans gave me this error:
main.cpp:39:25: error: ISO C++ forbids comparison between pointer and integer [-fpermissive]

anyone knows what this means?

Comment: Use `'-'`. to use the minus character (not a string consisting of a minus character).

Answer (score 2):

There are two problems with your code:

- You declare `i` that never changes. This is the same as doing `input[0]`
- You compare a character to a string. Instead of `"0"` (double quotes) you need `'0'` (single quotes).

Fixing these two problems will fix your code.

**Note:** You can write this function in a single line:

```
bool isNegative(string input) {
    return input[0] == '-';
}
```

Comment: Assuming the `input` is not empty, and does not begin with whitespace.  It might make more sense to convert the `string` to an `int` and then check for `< 0`.

Comment: @RemyLebeau That is true. I was trying to stay close to OP's code as much as possible.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use single quotes, which represent a single character, rather than using double quotes, which represent a string.

```
if (input[i] == '-')
```